# Fix all warnings in storyboard in static tableviewcontroller xcode 8

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, warnings, xcode8

We have the option to fix all the warning by selecting `UIView` and update all frames action, But I didn't find the same option with static `tableViewController` in `storyboard`. Is there any way to fix that automatically ?

Comment: what do you mean by " static tableViewController "

Comment: Drag and drop a TableViewController on Storyboard and Create static cells

Comment: There is no need to put any constraint on TableViewController but for tableViewCell you need to add constraints

Comment: You can do that by selecting tableViewCell from Document Outline and then select the resolve autolayout issues and select " Reset to suggested constraints  "

Answer (score 5):

In **Xcode 8.1 updated version**, there is a **shortcut** button for this.

Just select the problematic view's superview (containing mentioned constraints), and click this **update frames** button:

[image]